# Sorting lines with accented characters

Tags: sorting

When sorting the lines by `sort-lines` the lines beginning with `ä` comes after the lines starting with `z`. It would be nice if the lines could be sorted ignoring the accents, Umlauts, etc, like in a dictionary. Ideally a line starting with `ändern` should be come after a line starting with `anderen`.

There is simple solution for searching accented characters mentioned in https://superuser.com/a/675172/ but can not be used here. I am wondering if that solution can be adapted in this situation.

Comment: FYI, folding and grouping based on extended characters has been implemented in `isearch` and `query-replace` in the next version of emacs.

Answer (score 5):

I use this function for that

```el
(defun my-sort-lines ()
    (interactive)
    (shell-command-on-region (point-min) (point-max) "LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8 sort" (buffer-name) t ))
```

EDIT:
To sort region or buffer:

```el
  (defun my-sort-lines-buffer ()
    (interactive)
    (shell-command-on-region (point-min) (point-max) "LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8 sort" (buffer-name) t ))
  (defun my-sort-lines-region (start end) 
    (interactive "r") 
    (shell-command-on-region start end "LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8 sort" (buffer-name) t))
  (defun my-sort-lines-region-or-buffer ()
    (interactive)
    (save-excursion
      (if (region-active-p)
          (progn
            (my-sort-lines-region (region-beginning) (region-end))
            (message "Sorted selected region"))
        (progn
          (my-sort-lines-buffer)
          (message "Sorted buffer")))))
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing!  What about renaming to `my-sort-lines-buffer`? Or rewrite to `(defun my-sort-lines (start end)
  (interactive "r")
  (shell-command-on-region start end
   "LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8 sort" (buffer-name) t))`?

Comment: @Marco Wahl: I edit my post with your proposition.

Comment: When running this I get the error 'LC_COLLATE' is not recognized as a internal or external command nor an executable program.

Comment: @Name Maybe you are on Windows. Sorry this function only work on linux...